# How to handle softkeyboard show/hide events in android and iPhone in a hybrid app uses worklight?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

How to handle softkeyboard show/hide events in android and iPhone in a hybrid app uses worklight.

I'm using Worklight 6.1.0.01

Comment: Care the elaborate? i.e, what is wrong, or what exactly do you want to accomplish - the scenario.

Comment: I want invoke a javascript function when the softkeyboard is shown or hidden. And I also would like to know the keyboard's status at any point of time.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment, since it's not complete answer. But I've written a simple snippet for handling those issues: https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js . Check at least the source code to get an idea.

Comment: if you dont have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" set, then you can listen to a window resize like zvona script does.  But if you do have adjustpan set, then you will have to create a native listener that will call a javascript function.

Comment: in above i meant to say you can't use the screen resize if you have keyboard pan set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is working fine in both android and iOS

```
  document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", function(){
//keyboard is ON
  }, false);
  document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", function(){ 
//keyboard is OFF
  }, false);
```

Thank you